# VBA Settings Dialog using MVP - do I need a model?

Tags: vba, mvp

I've been reading up on many examples of MVP (Model-View-Presenter) and their variations (Passive view, Supervising view) to try and make my solutions more robust (and reusable) in VBA (using Excel as the host in this instance). The problem I've found is finding good, simple examples in VBA that are not complete overkill for the (hopefully) simple examples I need.

I'm attempting to create a "settings" dialogue that stores certain configuration in a worksheet (this is my "repository").

Here's my main procedure, triggered by the user:

```
Private Sub ShowImportSelector()
    Dim importPresenter As DataImportPresenter
    Set importPresenter = New DataImportPresenter

    importPresenter.LoadConfig
    If importPresenter.Show = -1 Then Exit Sub
    importPresenter.SaveConfig

    ' begin processing...
    If (CStr([Settings.SelectedVersion].Value2) = "QQ") Then
       ' ...
    End If

End Sub
```

Here is my "**presenter**" (here I use range names for the source, and config destination):

```
Option Explicit

Private m_importForm As FImport

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set m_importForm = New FImport
End Sub

Public Sub LoadConfig()
    m_importForm.SetAvailableVersions "tblVERSION"
    m_importForm.SetAvailableSalesOrgs "tblSALESORG"
    m_importForm.SetAvailableCategories "tblCATEGORY"
    m_importForm.ToolName = "Forecast"
End Sub

Public Sub SaveConfig()
    [Settings.SelectedVersion].Value2 = m_importForm.SelectedVersion
    [Settings.SelectedSalesOrg].Value2 = m_importForm.SelectedSalesOrg
    [Settings.SelectedCategory].Value2 = m_importForm.SelectedCategory
End Sub

Public Function Show() As Integer
    m_importForm.Show vbModal
    Show = m_importForm.Result
End Function
```

And now the "**View**" (a VBA Form):

```
Option Explicit

Private m_selectedVersion As String
Private m_selectedSalesOrg As String
Private m_selectedCategory As String
Private m_toolName As String
Private m_dialogueResult As Long

Public Property Get ToolName() As String
    ToolName = m_toolName
End Property

Public Property Let ToolName(ByVal value As String)
    m_toolName = value
    ToolNameLabel.Caption = value
End Property

Public Property Get Result() As Long
    Result = m_dialogueResult
End Property

Public Property Get SelectedVersion() As String
    SelectedVersion = m_selectedVersion
End Property

Public Property Get SelectedSalesOrg() As String
    SelectedSalesOrg = m_selectedSalesOrg
End Property

Public Property Get SelectedCategory() As String
    SelectedCategory = m_selectedCategory
End Property

Public Sub SetAvailableVersions(ByVal value As String)
    VersionSelector.RowSource = value
End Sub

Public Sub SetAvailableSalesOrgs(ByVal value As String)
    SalesOrgSelector.RowSource = value
End Sub

Public Sub SetAvailableCategories(ByVal value As String)
    CategorySelector.RowSource = value
End Sub

Private Sub SaveSelections()
    m_selectedVersion = VersionSelector.value
    m_selectedSalesOrg = SalesOrgSelector.value
    m_selectedCategory = CategorySelector.value
End Sub

Private Sub CloseButton_Click()
    m_dialogueResult = -1
    Me.Hide
End Sub

Private Sub ImportButton_Click()
    SaveSelections
    m_dialogueResult = 0
    Me.Hide
End Sub
```

At this point, I have become confused with the possible directions I could go in terms of adding a model to the above - question is: is this even needed for this simple example?

Comment: The "model" would be these properties you're currently exposing on the view. If you're happy with that, then you're good. Extracting the model from the view would make it easier to later test e.g. your presenter logic, by feeding it with a model that doesn't need a view.

Comment: I think this question might be a better fit on [codereview.se] (include the omitted code, too!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MVP architecture makes cleaner code, but cleaner code isn't the primary purpose of MVP; achieving *loose coupling*, *higher cohesion*, and *testability* is.

If loosely-coupled components and unit-testable logic isn't a requirement, then full-blown MVP is indeed overkill, and having the "model" exposed as properties on the "view" is definitely *good enough*, as it already helps making your "presenter" not need to care about form controls. You're treating the form as the object it's begging to be, and pragmatically speaking this could very well be all you need. I'd make the `Show` method return an explicit `Boolean` though, since it's implicitly used as such.

On the other hand, if you *are* shooting for decoupling and testability, then **extracting the model from the view would only be step one**: then you need to decouple the presenter from the worksheet, and maybe introduce some `ISettingsAdapter` interface that abstracts it away, such that if/when the configuration needs to go to a database or some .config file, your presenter code doesn't need to change in any way... but this requires designing the interfaces *without having any particular specific implementation in mind*, i.e. something that works without changes regardless of whether the data is on a worksheet, in some flat file, or in some database table.

MVP demands a paradigm shift: MVP isn't procedural programming anymore, it's OOP. Whether OOP is overkill for your needs depends on how much coupling you're willing to live with, and how frail this coupling is making your code in the face of future changes. Often, *abstraction* is enough: using named ranges instead of hard-coded range addresses is one way of improving the abstraction level; hiding the worksheet behind an adapter interface implemented by a worksheet proxy class (whatever you do, **never** make a worksheet module implement an interface: it *will* crash) is another - depends where your threshold for "overkill" is, but if you *do* achieve full decoupling *and write the unit tests*, nobody can blame you for going overboard: you're just following the industry best-practices that every programmer strives for, improving your skills, and making it much easier to later take that code and rewrite it in .NET, be it VB or C#. I doubt anyone would argue that full-blown MVP is overkill in .NET/WinForms.